# Is there any server performance monitor php script?

Tags: performance, monitoring, hosting

Basically I have a dedicated server that will be equally divided up and used by 5 users / accounts. Each user will be allocated an equal share of disk, transfer, etc., you get the idea. But with WHM /cPanel, it's impossible to impose hard limits on RAM and CPU processing time for each of the users / accounts - I mean, it's for VPS right? Not for shared environment. Or can WHM / cPanel do that - hard-limiting CPU time and RAM for each of the shared users?

So I need a way to monitor the server performance via a php script that constantly updates the server processes by user so I know when a user has been using too much of the server resources for a while and it starts to affect the performance of other users' websites. The script can be accessed on the Web to by all 5 users.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like Cacti: http://www.cacti.net/.

The thing is, if you want to have this automated, you'll need to have a cron running that checks processes using too much cpu/ram and then either sends a warning to the user or stops the process entirely.

I don't think you can impose hard-limits with cPanel/WHM.

Another solution might be splitting up the servers into virtual private servers, but this would mean purchasing cPanel/WHM licenses for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple shell script that can email you daily and provide you with resource usage reports:

http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2009/01/08/linux-script-to-collect-system-statistics-and-send-to-your-email/